# Json - JAVA (Eclipse)

Tags: java, json, eclipse

Como faço para ler um arquivo JSON (jsonl) através do eclipse em java? Preciso de algum package?

Answer (score 2):

Existem diversas bibliotecas para o efeito, mas recomendo [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Exemplo de JSON para JAVA:

```
Gson json = new Gson();
String string_json= "{\"ID\":\"9\",\"pais\":\"Korea\"}";
Info info= json.fromJson(string_json, Info.class);
```

[Tutorial GSON](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction/) - Link fornecido pelo readme do repositório oficial

Comment: Não trabalho com java, mas com uma pequena pesquisa você consegue saber a resposta para a sua pergunta.

Comment: Isso atende a [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)?

Comment: Desconhecia o site. Mas sim, penso não existir nenhuma descrepância com a norma, mas corrija se eu tiver errado :)